# Getting syntax file to load for typescriptreact files

Tags: neovim, conceal, filetype-typescript

I am very likely missing something very obvious, for I am very new to the vim world.

The effect I intended to achieve was to mimic the Inline Fold extension for vscode using vim's Conceal.

In short, I've made a syntax file! and it works!

```
set conceallevel=2

syntax match Normal '\vclassName\=".{-}"'ms=s+11,me=e-1 conceal cchar=
```

Now the crux. I have this .vim file, and I can manually source it, but I wish for it to come up when I open up a tsx file.

Now, my understanding is, you just slap it in `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim` and bobs your uncle.

So my first step was to see what filetype I was interacting with, which after running `:set ft` I am greeted with `filetype=typescriptreact`.

So neat, I put my file in `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/typescriptreact.vim` annnddd... no cigar.

I also tried `~/.config/nvim/syntax/typescriptreact.vim`, again, no cigar

I notice that running `:set syntax` results in `syntax=`, and I had wondered if that is specific to `typescriptreact` being funny, however this is also true for when I open a Rust file.

If I have missed any crucial info please let me know! I am honestly out of ideas.

E: This is also my first SE/SO post ever, sorry if I broke any taboo

E2: https://www.github.com/zynh0722/nvim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`syntax` will not work so long as I have treesitter enabled. The correct path is to use treesitter to achieve this goal. `:h treesitter-highlight-conceal`

In theory disabling treesitter would allow that syntax file to load, however that doesn't solve my specific use case, as disabling TS is a none-starter.

Comment: It would be good if you could write what you did to solve your problem. I'm sure it will help others.

Comment: My problem has become a ts query issue now, if I disabled treesitter the syntax file would probably load, but honestly idk, as that path isn't a direction I wish to head, unfortunately this question was never really answered in the direction I intended, so I made this answer, which explains why it doesn't work. 

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41685/how-to-apply-ts-directive-to-correct-child

Comment: nonetheless I've added that disabling treesitter might work, havent really checked though

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that syntax is not activated.
I recommend you add the following statement in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file:

```
syntax enable
```

With this statement when Vim set the filetype it also set the syntax and search for a syntax file. It should then find your addition.

Comment: I tried calling syntax enable from my init.lua with `vim.cmd('syntax enable')` as well as switching to a vim file and just embedding my lua config into it and caling `syntax enable` from there. But nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Do you still have no syntax for `typescriptreact` files? What is the result of the `:set syntax?` command?

Comment: Same thing as before, `syntax=`. Just as a sanity check, I get the same thing for Rust

Comment: It seems syntax if off on your configuration. Could you tell me the result of the following command: `:echo g:syntax_on`? Could you try by running Neovim with the `--clean` flag (i.e `nvim --clean`) it deactivates the plugins.

Comment: Could you tell us what is the version of Vim you are running (what is the result of the Vim command `:version`)

Comment: version `0.8.3 Release`, it's the brew arm64 build

Comment: `g:syntax_on` is `1`. Running with --clean didn't seem to do much, either way g:syntax_on is 1

Comment: Do you have colorization in the typescriptreact file? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: [heres](https://imgur.com/a/ddIf5Tt) a screenshot, colors have worked just fine

Comment: I've done more investigating, I may have overlooked treesitter, so I sat around trying to get a query to do what I want, just to find out I cant even get queries to load for typescriptreact, either that or I dont know how they work.